# Input keeps missing record at end of line

Tags: sas

I am learning little sas book. Below is a code from book. and raw data. The issue is when I run it, the final data set keeps missing the record at end of line, i.e., it keeps missing 75 and 56, and label them as missing ("."). Could anyone point out where could possible be the problem? When I add spaces after 75 and 56 at line ends, the problem is gone.

```
DATA class;
INFILE 'c:\MyRawData\Scores.dat';
INPUT Score @@;
RUN;
PROC UNIVARIATE DATA = class;
VAR Score;
TITLE;
RUN;
```

Data in that file:

```
56 78 84 73 90 44 76 87 92 75
85 67 90 84 74 64 73 78 69 56
87 73 100 54 81 78 69 64 73 65
```

after run it shows more like

```
56 78 84 73 90 44 76 87 92 .
85 67 90 84 74 64 73 78 69 .
87 73 100 54 81 78 69 64 73 65
```

Comment: Did you type the data into the file, or cut/paste or otherwise obtain the file?  What OS are you running this in (you clearly have the file in Windows, but is SAS actually running in Windows?)

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that you have something wrong with your end of lines; either you have a spurious character, or your end of line isn't correct in some fashion.  Most likely you are using a windows file and you are running in Unix, so you have

```
75CRLF85
```

and since Unix uses only LF for line terminator, it sees "75CR" endofline "85", not "75" endofline "85" like it should.

In that case you can either do what you did - add a space, though that likely will still leave some 'blank' records in there - or use `TERMSTR` in your `infile` statement to tell SAS how to properly read the file in.

Otherwise, you may have some spurious end characters - for example, if you pasted this from the web, it's possible you have a non-breaking space that is not converted to a regular space.

You can find out by doing this:

```
data _null_;
  infile 'c:\rawdata\myfile.dat';
  input @;
  put _infile_ $HEX60.;
run;
```

The 60 is 2x the length of the line.  That tells you what SAS is seeing.  What you should see:

```
3536203738203834203733203930203434203736203837203932203735
3835203637203930203834203734203634203733203738203639203536
383720373320313030203534203831203738203639203634203733203635
```

Digits in ASCII are 30+digit, so 35 is a 5, 36 is a 6, etc.  Space is 20. The first line:

```
35|36|20|37|38|20|38|34|20|37|33|20| ...
```

so  5 6 space 7 8 space 3 8 space 7 3 space.  If you see something else after the 37 35, then you know there is a problem.  You might see any of the following:

- `0A` = Line feed.
- `0D` = Carriage return.
- `A0` = Nonbreaking (web) space.

There are lots of other things you could see, but those are the most likely to trip you up.  Pasting from the web is often a problem.

Comment: Great answer. As the text was probably copied from a PDF on windows you're probably spot on. The simplest diagnostic/solution would be to manually delete and retype the problem areas (...7`5       8`5...), assuming the file is on the same system as SAS.

Comment: PDF is a good point.  Almost as bad as copying from code written in Outlook emails (with smartquotes and such)...

Comment: Joe, thanks for the great answer. Indeed it is data files from window and I use it in unix system. I think it is exactly what you suspected. Unfortunately it is sas 8.5x, there is no termstr I could use.

Comment: If that's the case then you can convert them via several methods - ftp using ascii transfer for example, or utilities available online.